# Tabletools initialization options not applying

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to add some settings to my datatables/tabletools init but for some reason no matter what settings I change for tabletools the default options still show (I.e. Copy should be > "Copy to Clipboard" and it remains as "Copy"). When I click the buttons they function so I know it's finding my SWF. I am using the latest version of tabletools and datatables.

I've tried both the old hungarian notation:

`"oTableTools": { "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "copy", "sButtonText": "Copy to Clipboard", "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"sExtends": "print"}, {"sExtends": "csv", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"sExtends": "pdf", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"sExtends": "xls", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]} ] }`

as well as

`"tableTools": { "buttons": [ {"extends": "copy", "buttonText": "Copy to Clipboard", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"extends": "print"}, {"extends": "csv", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"extends": "pdf", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]}, {"extends": "xls", "columns": [1,2,3,4,5]} ] }`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper initialization is shown below. See [TableTools example](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/button_text.html) for demonstration.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "sButtonText": "Copy to Clipboard",
                "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "print"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "mColumns": [1,2,3,4,5]
            }
        ]
    }
} );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and sry for late response. I had actually figured this out doing exactly what you said. I am a bit baffled that they now use the non-hungarian "tableTools" identifier but then go on to use things like "sExtends" and "mColumns" as opposed to "extends" and "columns" respectively. Thank you for the response though and I'll mark your answer as correct.